# How can I use castellated vias with a breadboard?

Tags: soldering

I dabble with soldering every once in a while to the extent of soldering pins into through holes for prototyping but I have never worked with this type of packaging before.

[image]

The pads aren't really through holes per say, but i am still confused. Is there a way I could attach pins to these to work with a breadboard? Thank you for your help!

Comment: They are called castellated vias. You solder them to pads on a carrier board. [see here](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-solder---castellated-mounting-holes) for an example.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CVeGd2Khhug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The connections on that board are called castellated vias.

To connect it to a carrier board, you place pads on the carrier that line up with the castellations and then connect the two with solder.

For prototyping, if the pins are spaced correctly, you can solder them directly onto the copper side of stripboard (Veroboard). Just remember to cut the strings underneath the daughterboard so you don't accidentally short out something on the back.

---

There is an example SparkFun tutorial [here](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-solder---castellated-mounting-holes). In case of link rot, here are some pictures from that example (CC BY-SA 4.0).

An example daughter board:

[image: Daughter Board]

An example carrier board:

[image: Carrier Board]

And the two connected:

[image: Soldered]

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to solder some pin headers straight to the board by using a breadboard as a jig. If the spacing is wrong Then I would use an intermediary board as tom suggested.